# How can you ensure a Symfony embeddedForm's object is bound to the form's object?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

```
Production:
  image_id

Image:
  id
```

The ImageForm is embedded on the ProductionForm and the image is optional. The issue is that when adding an Image to an **already existing** Production via the embeddedForm and not changing any standard values in the Production form, the main form is not saved (Production has no changes).. except that its `image_id` needs updating.

I'm in two minds whether the problem is that I've incorrectly setup these forms or whether I need to add something into a save method binding.

Note this issue doesn't occur if the production isNew i.e. you're adding a new production and image all at once- or if you're editing a production (i.e. changing its name another field) AND adding an image. Or if you're editing an image that is already bound.

I understand loosely why this is occurring, and the order Symfony executes saves in forms.. but I don't know what to add to make this work.

There's not much code involved thus far, only what is found on the advanced forms jobeet; I'm using `$this->embedRelation('Image');` and a post validator + saveEmbeddedForms override to avoid blank images being saved.

---

In summary: the problem is that if you are adding an image to a production that already exists without changing any values that are stored in the production table, the image is saved, but not related to the production, the image_id stored in the production table remains null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with `$this->getObject()->setUpdatedAt(date('c'));`.. a less hacky solution would be appreciated.